# Grabbing a song uploaded via Paperclip, stored in S3, played with jPlayer (Ruby)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, paperclip, jplayer

I am struggling with the following:

In my webapp, I am uploading mp3 files (or mpeg) via paperclip, which works on local. I am also linking the upload with Amazon S3, which also works (I can see in my bucket the uploaded songs, no errors on server side).

So, the upload part works fine.

Now, I am having a hard time "grabbing" my audio files and playing them via jPlayer, a jQuery based media player.

I tested the player with a URL, and it works perfectly well.

Here is what I've done, I am using ruby 2.3.0 and Rails 5.

Model:

```
class Episode < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :podcast

  has_attached_file :episode_thumbnail, styles: { large: "1000x1000#", medium: "550x550#" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :episode_thumbnail, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/

  has_attached_file :mp3
  validates_attachment :mp3, :content_type => { :content_type => ["audio/mpeg", "audio/mp3"] }, :file_name => { :matches => [/mp3\Z/]}
end
```

I am also permitting the mp3 in my params:

Controller:

```
def episode_params
    params.require(:episode).permit(:title, :description, :episode_thumbnail, :mp3)
end
```

My form looks like this:

```
<div class="field">
        <%= f.label :mp3 %><br>
        <%= f.file_field :mp3 %>
</div>
```

Eventually, here is the script I am using with jPlayer, and that's where I think there's something wrong, that I can't figure out:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
   ready: function () {
    $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
        mp3: "<%= @episode.mp3.url %>";
    });
   },
   swfPath: "/js",
   supplied: "mp3"
  });
 });
</script>
```

The view of the player looks like this:

```
<!-- jPlayer -->
    <div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer"></div>
    <div id="jp_container_1" class="jp-audio">
        <div class="jp-type-single">
            <div class="jp-gui jp-interface">
                <div class="jp-controls">
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-play" tabindex="1">&#333333;</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-pause" tabindex="1">&#333333;</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-mute" tabindex="1">&#333333;</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-unmute" tabindex="1">&#333333;</a></li>
                </div>

                <div class="jp-progress">
                    <div class="jp-seek-bar">
                        <div class="jp-play-bar"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="jp-volume-bar">
                    <div class="jp-volume-bar-value"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="jp-time-holder">
                    <div class="jp-current-time"></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="jp-no-solution">
                <span>Update Required</span>
                To play the media you will need to either update your browser to a recent version or update your <a href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/" target="_blank">Flash plugin</a>.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<!-- end jPlayer -->
```

In my opinion, the <%= @episode.mp3.url %> can be the problem here, once again, I've tried with a random URL storing a MP3 file, and it works well.

Any thoughts on this will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try get `@episode.mp3.url` and directly open it in browser? Probably mp3 stored as a private object.

Comment: The file path shows up when I try this yes, so I guess the mp3 objects are accessible.

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM SOLVED, FINALLY!

Here is the piece of script than you need to use in order to make it run!

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {

  $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
    ready: function(event) {
      $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
        mp3: "<%= @episode.mp3.url %>",
      });
    },
    swfPath: "http://jplayer.org/latest/dist/jplayer",
    supplied: "mp3, oga",
    wmode: "window",
    useStateClassSkin: true,
    autoBlur: false,
    smoothPlayBar: true,
    keyEnabled: true,
    remainingDuration: true,
    toggleDuration: true
  });
});
</script>
```